# Add dynamic description and canonical via Middleman and HAML

Tags: yaml, haml, middleman

Trying to add acanonical link tags to the head of my Middleman App document via HAML but not sure how to do it.

```
%link(rel="canonical" href="current_page.data.canonical")
```

Using YAML such as

```
---
title: Swan Physio
description: This is the description
canonical : http://swanphysio.co.uk
---
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
%link(rel="canonical" href='http://example.com#{current_page.url}')
```